# How to align images contained in a ul in some sort image gallery

Tags: css, singularitygs

I have a symmetrical grid. i've set my output type to float with 6 columns. My goal was to display list items out of an unordered list, images in this case, in some sort of an image gallery ([gist](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8384145)).

**mobile layout:** all images 100% in width vertically aligned.

**bp500px:** each image is 3 columns wide - works in nicely.

**bp750px:** each image is 2 columns wide - the layout breaks.

does the float-span doesn't apply to the second item in the list - but basically float-span(2) is set for each item number 1 and 2 and float-span(2,last) for each third?

or is the combination $output: float and float-span already the wrong choice for that kind of goal in a symmetrical grid environment? better to go with the isolation mixins?

Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to debug if there were code associated with it, but presumably for your **bp500px** you have something like `li:nth-of-type(even)` for `last`. That has a higher selector weight than simply `li`, and since media queries have a lower selector weight than pseudo selectors, you need to do one of the following things:

- Undo the `:nth-of-type(even)` selector in **bp750px** by re-calling it with the span you want
  _ Fencing **bp500px** so that instead of `(min-width: 500px)` you use `(min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 749px)`

Comment: ah cooooooool! works. i always tend to forget that if i don't define an upper limit of a breakpoint its properties stay still active. but works like a charm now. thanks!

Comment: and i don't have had more code. it was just a simple test case for trying to get that images aligned in a grid thing working. therefor i haven't had more lines to share. :/